# silently truncating django model char field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to do a mass import of data into an existing database. Sometimes the string fields in this other database contain strings that are larger than the field I'm importing them into. I'm OK with this, I'd like the system to just silently truncate, but I'm getting a warning which then also halts execution.

Since this is a live database, I'm running my code via "manage.py shell" and and when I call the import routine it halts after the first string field it encounters that's too long. Oddly it DOES insert it into the database truncated as I expect, but then exits the for loop.

Thanks!

Here's the error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/blah/blah/update.py", line 41, in updateCommunities
    community.save()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/db/models/base.py", line 434, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/db/models/base.py", line 527, in save_base
    result = manager._insert(values, return_id=update_pk, using=using)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/db/models/manager.py", line 195, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, values, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/db/models/query.py", line 1479, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 783, in execute_sql
    cursor = super(SQLInsertCompiler, self).execute_sql(None)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 727, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/db/backends/util.py", line 15, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 86, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 168, in execute
    if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 82, in _warning_check
    warn(w[-1], self.Warning, 3)
Warning: Data truncated for column 'community_name' at row 1
```

Comment: Can you print the warning?